# Best way to declare Fragment dependencies for test- and readability?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, testing, android-testing

Basically there are two ways which i know of:

- Pass the dependency through newInstance
- Retrieve the depencency through onAttach

Both methods seem to get the job done.

However the first method, is very much like the usual way of declaring dependencies through a constructor, but it requires the passed dependency to implement the Parcelable interface, which is not always possible, or wanted. (eg. database DAO and repository)

The second method retrieves the dependencies when it gets attach to a context. This way it's possible to ask the context if it has, certain dependencies needed for the fragment to function. It seems like a very clean and efficient way, but the problem with this is it hides dependencies, and makes it harder to test.

So my question is this: Is there a third way? Or is there some way to make either method have the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) to inject dependencies into your fragment. After you have set it up, you can just annotate a member of your fragment with the `@Inject` annotation and Dagger 2 will provide an instance of a required class. And it's possible to replace your dependencies in tests.

Comment: I have looked a bit into dagger, the problem is just that i can't really isolate the fragment, when testing.

Comment: You can use a container activity such as SingleFragmentActivity (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/debug/java/com/android/example/github/testing/SingleFragmentActivity.java) to test your fragment. If you say that you cannot isolate your fragment, than it's tightly coupled to the rest of your application and should be refactored.

Comment: No, what i mean is, i have to call AndroidInjection.inject in the fragment, and that in itself is something i want to avoid, since it as you state, creates tight coupling.

Comment: You can check my article (section Dependency Injection) to see how I avoided having AndroidInjection.inject(f) - https://proandroiddev.com/testing-user-interface-of-android-app-with-architecture-components-data-binding-and-dagger-2-5d15c3779807. It allowed to not have Dagger injection in tests.

Comment: Ahh that's pretty clever :-)